# Ruby: For loop inside iteration caused the array to be filled with "range" class of items

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, for-loop, iteration

There is a 2 dimensional array, which is filled by "0" by default. I want to create another array which holds the number of "non 0" items for each column, so, the length of the second array is same with the number of columns of the 2 dimensional array.

Here is the code I'm having problem with, I initialized the 1D array with a fixed length (number of columns of the 2D array)

```
column_depth=Array.new(8) {0}
```

Iterating through the 2D array and for every non-0 element of each column, I want to increase the corresponding value in the 1D array:

```
column_depth.map! do |a|
for i in 0..6
    play_field[i].each do |b|
        if b != "0"
            a = a+1
        end
    end
end
end #outer map (column_depth)
```

However, when I print out the contents of the column_depth Array, I get the following result:

```
0..6
0..6
0..6
0..6
0..6
0..6
0..6
0..6
```

I am totally confused with this output, howcome it could assign the range of the for loop to the value "a"?  (tested input is all-zero matrix for play_field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create an array then modify it. Just

```
column_depth = play_field.map{|col| col.count{|n| n != 0}}
```

For counting non-zero numbers in the other dimension of `play_field`,

```
row_depth = play_field.transpose.map{|row| row.count{|n| n != 0}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, this is almost doing what I'm trying to achieve (does it for the rows instead of columns). Using the map function for dynamically creating the result array is definetely a better approach.

Comment: Indeed this is a very sophisticated response to what I was trying to do with a much longer way. I'll study that usage to understand the logic better.

Answer (score 1):

`map!` updates an array by replacing each value with whatever the supplied block evaluates to. Reassigning the block argument has no effect.

As you've written it the block will evaluate to whatever the `for` expression evaluates to, which is always the thing iterated over (in this case the range)

All you need to do is change it so that the last line in the block evaluates to the result you want.

As an aside you could replace the block contents with something like

```
a + play_field[0..6].count {|b| b != "0}
```

It's very rare to need to iterate over a range of integers as a way of iterating over a collection.

Comment: Ah, I deleted my comment saying something similar because when I read back over it I thought I'd made a mistake, but I'm glad to see I was almost right with my interpretation. +1.

Comment: John's comment made me start thinking on the same spot, and seeing your more detailed response has been very helpful, thanks for that.